# Can I restore a mongo db from within mongo shell?

Tags: python, mongodb, prolog, mongodump, mongorestore

Dumping and restoring a mongo db seems fairly straightforward when you are using the shell anyway: you just use the commands [`mongorestore`](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/) and [`mongodump`](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/). But if I am not mistaken, these commands require you to leave your active [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/).

Furthermore, when writing in Python or Prolog I have different ways of communicating with mongo. I can either use PyMonogo or in my case, I am communicating via [RosProlog](https://github.com/knowrob/rosprolog/tree/master/src). Both can execute mongo shell commands but I can't figure out a way to execute something similar to `mongorestore` and `mongodump`.

Of course I could use `os.system()` in Python (or `process_create/3` in prolog) to execute shell-commands, but it seems very ugly and I would like to avoid it. I could also write a .bson-parser myself but is that really necessary? Is there really no equivalent in the mongo shell?

Comment: No, you don't need any mongo shell active. `mongorestore/mongodump` are plain stand-alone executables, actually there is no other way to run them. You cannot restore a database from mongo shell.

Comment: Could you confirm whether you want to restore from mongo sell or from python script? You  started the question asking about interactive mongo shell and ended with a workaround from python system call.

Comment: I want to restore it from a python script, preferably using PyMongo.

Comment: As far as I understand, PyMongo can execute anything the mongo shell can, too

Comment: Mongo shell is a javascript interactive environment. It comes with it's own set of utilities and helper functions which may differ from what is available in PyMongo.

Answer (score 2):

mongodump and mongorestore are OS level utilities written in golang https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools. You indeed need to run them outside the mongo shell.

The recommended way is to use standard mongodump and mongorestore as subprocesses yet there is no magic there and you can do the same in Python.

From https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-664:

```
from bson import BSON, decode_all
from pymongo import MongoClient
 
client = MongoClient()
source_collection = client.db.collection
 
# Dump.
with open('file.bson', 'wb+') as f:
    for doc in source_collection.find():
        f.write(BSON.encode(doc))
 
# Restore.
target_collection = client.db.collection2
with open('file.bson', 'rb') as f:
    target_collection.insert(decode_all(f.read()))
```

It won't be as efficient, the backups won't be compatible with standard backups, and you may miss some edge cases without dumping oplog.

Answer (score 1):

This python solution works on windows and linux; sure it's a bit hacky but hardly ugly.

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.run(['mongodump', '--uri', 'mongodb://localhost', '--readPreference', 'primary'], capture_output=True)
print(output)
```

Add in whatever additional parameters you need, e.g. `f'--archive={my_file}'`